# Are ongoing fetch requests cancelled after changing window.location?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch

I noticed that some fetch requests don't reach the server when I change window.location just after sending the request (location change is not inside the promise response handler).

I tested on Chrome browser

```
# util.js
function sendLog(payload) {
  const urlApi = `http://api.example.com/public/send-message`;
  return fetch(urlApi, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  });
}

# main.js
sendLog({
    project: 'FrontEnd-Card',
    countryId: country
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
window.location.replace(REDIRECT_URL);
```

I noticed this pattern:
If network is fast, the log is successfully sent to the server
If network is slow, the log doesn't reach the server.

Somehow redirection kills the outgoing request. Is this true ? Where can I find a detailed documentation about this behavior ?

Comment: When you reload the page, any scripts that were running on the old page are stopped, and outstanding AJAX requests are cancelled. I don't know where it's documented, but scripts are associated with the currently loaded page.

Comment: Why don't you wait for the response before changing the location, so you can be sure that the fetch request completes?

Comment: I thought that if was enough to trigger the request and it will eventually reach the backend. I didn't want to wait for the response so the redirection happens faster ( I want to redirect no matter what is the response of my logging request). Now, I assume that the request is still held on the browser and If I change the location of the page, the request will never been sent. If the request has already left my browser, it doesn't make sense that it'll be cancelled if I change my location url.

Comment: I think `fetch()` merely queues the outgoing request, it doesn't actually send it. Then `window.location.replace()` cancels it before it's sent.